# Set “seed” for random number generation with Temporary tables in Redshift Sql?

Tags: sql, random, amazon-redshift, random-seed

How to use a “seed” for random number generation with Temporary tables in Redshift Sql?

```
-- Without temp table seed works: result is always 21

set seed to .25;
select cast (random() * 100 as int);


-- With temp table seed does not work, i.e. the result is always different : 

set seed to .25;
drop table  if exists a;
CREATE TEMP TABLE a 
as(select cast (random() * 100 as int));
select * from a;

set seed to .25;
drop table  if exists a;
CREATE TEMP TABLE a 
as(select cast (random() * 100 as int));
select * from a;
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff database is amazon-reshift. Iadded the tag. "With temp table seed does not work" means that the result is always different. I added this to the question.

Comment: can you elaborate your requirements? you may be able to use md5 or a python function. Please take a step back and explain what you are tring to do and why.

Comment: Using a Redshift SQL query, I would like to randomly select rows within a temporary table.  This is 10000 products for each category such as: set SESSION seed to .25;CREATE TEMP TABLE DATA_TABLE_SAMPLE
AS (
 SELECT
  a.*
 FROM   DATA_TABLE  a
 join  ( select PRODUCTS,  CATEGORY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  CATEGORY ORDER BY random() DESC) as rn  from (select  PRODUCTS,  CATEGORY from DATA_TABLE group by PRODUCTS,CATEGORY )  ) b on (a.PRODUCTS=b.PRODUCTS and a.CATEGORY=b.CATEGORY)    
 where     rn <=10000 
);

Comment: @peter . . . I see this as always 21 for all three in Postgres.  This must be something strange in Redshift.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Thanks for this feedback. 

At All: Could anyone confirm the same issue on Redshift? I tested it with two different clusters and it seems that "set seed " is just ignored for the temp table which appears quite strange. 
Is there a possibility to use "set seed" within a temp table via a different syntax?

Comment: @peter . . . If I had so speculate, `set seed` is run on the lead node, but the actual randomization would be on the compute nodes.

Comment: Okay, thanks @Gordon for the hint. I tried to use "ALTER USER enter_user_name set seed to .25;"   (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Modifying_the_default_settings.html). But this did not change the result.

Comment: Even as a regular (non-temp) table the seed doesn't set.